# Problems with mysql and XMLHttpRequest + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I would like to add a search function for my Mysql database. So if I type 'Test' it shows all users with the word Test in it. But the communication from my php document to the Mysql `SELECT` .... Doc doesn't work for me. I would like that after clicking 'search' the results are shown below the search input part (in the `#search_name_log`s div).

Here is the main PHP script:

```
<script>

function submitSearch(){
var search = searchtermname.value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('GET','findusername.php?search='+search);
xmlhttp.send(); 

var searchname_result = xmlhttp.load('GET','findusername.php?search='+search);

$('#search_name_logs').load(searchname_result);
}

</script>

(...)
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="pmaddtalk_box_name"><span id="open_add_name" style="cursor:pointer;"><div>
<img src="png/find_user-50.png" class="pmaddtalk_icon">
<p class="pmaddtalk_find_text">Search by Name</p>
</div></span>
<article id="open_now_add_name">
<input name="searchtermname" class="boxformal boxformal-search" placeholder="Search by Name"></input>
<a href="#" onClick="submitSearch()" class="search_btn">Search</a><br>
<div id="search_name_logs"></div>
<br><br>
</article>
<script>
$("#open_add_name").click(function() {
$( "#open_now_add_name" ).toggle( "blind" );
});
</script>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP MySQL connection script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$search = $_REQUEST['search'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db('ibm',$con);
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$search'");

while($extract = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<p>" . $extract['username'] . "</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: When you try to access `PHP` only does it echos?

Comment: @void I would like the echo be shown in the '#search_name_logs' div.... How can I do this?

Comment: Yes i understand that, But what I am asking is when you try to access `yourfile.php?search=test` does it echos what is need to echo?

Comment: @void If i open the second script (the echo script) it works. So if I e.g. open yourfile.php?search=User1 it shows me the existing user. So this part of the script should not be the problem.. But I don't get the echo into the div :/

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of extra work here that you don't need to do. Also you're mis-using the jQuery `load()` method. The `load()` method can replace all of your XMLHttpRequest code.

All you need to do is this:

```
// Select the element where the result is going to go
var resultHolder = $('#search_name_logs');

function submitSearch(){

     // You don't show it but I assume searchtermname holds a reference to your input
     var search = searchtermname.value;

     // Load the contents of the URL into the result element
     resultHolder.load('findusername.php?search='+search);

     // Don't follow the link
     return false;
}
```

Also, not relevant to the question but you'd never want to use your PHP script as it is on a real site as it's vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can find plenty more articles which cover this and how to avoid it, just Google it.

Comment: You should use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.